# Establishing the number of values yielded by a generator

Tags: python, python-3.x

Suppose I have code along these lines:

```
counter = Counter()
text = f.read()
words = words_generator(text)
interesting_words = filter_generator(words)
counter.update(interesting_words)

for i in counter:
    print("Frequency for "+i ": "+counter[i]/sum)
```

How should I best set the value of `sum` which is the number of values yielded by `words_generator`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
from collections import Counter

class CountItemsWrapper:
    def __init__(self, items):
        self.items = iter(items)
        self.count = 0

    def __next__(self):
        res = next(self.items)
        self.count += 1
        return res

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

counter = Counter()
text = f.read()
words = CountItemsWrapper(words_generator(text))
interesting_words = filter_generator(words)
counter.update(interesting_words)

for i in counter:
    print("Frequency for "+i ": "+counter[i]/words.count)
```

Basically, `CountItemsWrapper` is an iterator that just passes through values, but keeps count whenever it does.

You can then just use the `count` attribute on the wrapper as your `sum`.

---

Explanation of the class:

```
def __init__(self, items):
    self.items = iter(items)
    self.count = 0
```

This is simple. Keep in mind that instances are *iterators*, not *just* iterables. So this iterates *once*, keeping count *once*.

---

```
def __next__(self):
    res = next(self.items)
    self.count += 1
    return res
```

This is called to get the next item.`self.count` must be added *after* the call to `next` because we allow the StopIteration to propagate and don't want to add to the count if we haven't yielded a value.

---

```
def __iter__(self):
    return self
```

This is an iterator so it returns itself.

Answer (score 2):

Q&D posssible technical solution : wrap your generator into an iterable that keeps track of the number of items seens, ie:

```
class IterCount(object):
    def __init__(self, iterable):
        self._iterable = iterable
        self._count = 0

    def _itercount(self):
        for value in self._iterable:
            self._count += 1
            yield value

    def __iter__(self):
        return self._itercount()

    @property
    def count(self):
        return self._count


itc1 = IterCount(range(10))
print list(itc1)
print itc1.count

itc2 = IterCount(xrange(10))
print list(itc2)
print itc2.count
```

Comment: You could simply put the code of `_itercount` inside `__iter__`(yes, `__iter__` can be a generator).

Comment: I don't see why you've made this reiterable as the count doesn't reset. This means that it's "broken" if you use it in multiple loops, I think. You should move `self._count` from a class variable to a variable on the iterator.

Comment: @Veedrac Who said that it is re-iterable? That code is exactly equivalent to yours. The only difference is that it uses a generator to avoid to define `__next__`(and fails in his purpose since he his defining another useless method in order to do this, which I don't understand. Either define `__iter__` + `__next__`, or `__iter__` as a generator.)

Comment: It's not equivalent. I'll host a snippet on Github showing the differing behaviour.

Comment: This was just (as mentioned) a very Q&D example - I seldom write proper iterators and I didn't have time to come with anything better. Veedrac's answer is of course way better.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is to build a list:

```
words = list(words_generator(text))
```

An other option is to use `itertools.tee`:

```
words, words_copy = itertools.tee(words_generator(text))
```

Afterwards you can use both copy of the iterable. However note that if you first iterate completely over a copy then it will be faster and more memory efficient to simply build the list. To see any gain memory-wise you should somehow iterate on both copies "at the same time".
For example something like:

```
filtered = filter_generator(words)
total = 0
for word, _ in zip(filtered, words_copy): # use itertools.izip in python2
    counter[word] += 1
    total += 1
total += sum(1 for _ in words_copy)
```

Which uses at most `O(n-k)` memory where `n` is the number of words in the text and `k` is the number of interesting words in the text. You may simplify the code a bit using:

```
from itertools import zip_longest #izip_longest in python2
filtered = filter_generator(words)
total = 0
for word, _ in zip_longest(filtered, words_copy):
    counter[word] += 1
    total += 1
del counter[None]
```

Which uses only `O(1)` memory(if the generators are constant-space).

Note however that having explicit loops will slow down the code, so in the end, if memory is not an option, building a `list` for `words` may be the better solution.